# How to get same name record in one row in data table

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach

I have got the same customer name in some records in one row in a data table. I have a MySQL structure like this:

```
id name  hour date

1  test  10  09-09-2019
2  test  8   08-09-2019
```

How can I get a customer name test record like the one shown below? Is this possible or not with a MySQL query or any for / foreach loop using in php?

```
name  08-09-2019(hour)  09-09-2019(hour) totalhour

test   8                  10               18
```

when i used group by name than i have get only one record hour according to asc/desc and i remove group by than fetch record than i have show two record two row in data table but i need in two diff. date hour record in same row with total ,i show above, thanks

Comment: it's called 'pivot table'. And with mysql it seems to be impossible if you don't know list  of date values before. Doing it by php code is easier

Comment: i get date using date range filter and submit record than i get date

Comment: What a problem you have with getting the result by a loop ?

Comment: i get result with two row like first record print than same customer name second row print, but i need same name record in one row